# Wget failing to detect SVG files when downloading a website

Tags: linux, download, wget

I used this command to recursively download the website, but the linked SVG files hosted on the asset's subdomain are not downloaded.

`wget --load-cookies cookies.txt --mirror --recursive --level=5 --no-parent --page-requisites --domains=LINK,assets.LINK -H --convert-links --adjust-extension --header="referer: LINK" LINK`

I tried changing the command so it would only download SVG:s, but it seems that `wget` does not even notice that there are linked SVG:s in the HTML file.

Anything I can do to get `wget` to detect the images?